# Letter Index script in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script in bash to achieve a requirement described in the following example:

Eg: User inputs a sentence : "this is a book"
The Output must be "20 8 9 19 9 19 1 2 15 15 11" which is based on the alphabetical sequence.

Following is the code to achieve the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter a sentence"
read sent

alpha=(" " {a..z})

for i in $(seq 27)
do
 [ $i -eq 27 ] && break
 eval ${alpha[$i]}=$i
done


eval echo $sent | tr -d [:punct:][:space:] | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | fold -w1 | paste -sd " "| sed -e 's/\</\$/g'
```

Could someone guide me as to where i am going wrong or if there is a better way to approach the problem.

Comment: A starting point might be the function `ord` in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92448/2782).

Answer (score 0):

I know we should avoid doing full programs, but this was not a bad exercise:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter a sentence: "
sentence="$(echo $REPLY | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr -dc [:alpha:])"
for (( i=0; i<${#sentence}; i++ ));
  do echo -n "$(($(printf "%d " "'${sentence:$i:1}") - 96 )) "
done
echo
```